# JPA reuse some "previous" JDBC login credentials

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, jdbc, authentication

I don't know if this is really a bug ... it seems that something remains "open".
I'm using EclipseLink 2.5 with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.
In the second call at the createEntityManagerFactory method a wrong password is ignored and everything works as well ...
Do I have to reset or clean some kind of Connection or Session Object ?

```
    String userId = "sa";
    String psw = "rightPassword";
    Map<String, Object> paramsConnect = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    paramsConnect.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", userId);
    paramsConnect.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", psw);

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU", paramsConnect);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Tab1");
    List<Object[]> rows = q.getResultList();
    System.err.println(rows.get(0));

    em.clear();
    em.close();
    emf.close();

    psw = "wrongPassword";
    EntityManagerFactory emf1 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU", paramsConnect);
    EntityManager em1 = emf1.createEntityManager();
    Query q1 = em1.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Tab2");
    List<Object[]> rows1 = q1.getResultList();
    System.err.println(rows1.get(0));
```

Comment: You're not changing the psw inside the paramsConnect Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the value with key 'javax.persistence.jdbc.password' in your HashMap you need to change the line:

```
psw = "wrongPassword";
```

with the line:

```
paramsConnect.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "wrongPassword");
```

The method put will replace the value of an existing key and will create it if doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry ... I was sleeping :-)